# VB.NET Inputbox - How to identify when the Cancel Button is pressed?

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple windows application that pops up an input box for users to enter in a date to do searches.

How do I identify if the user clicked on the Cancel button, or merely pressed OK without entering any data as both appear to return the same value?

I have found some examples of handling this in VB 6 but none of them really function in the .NET world.

Ideally I would like to know how to handle the empty OK and the Cancel seperately, but I would be totally ok with just a good way to handle the cancel.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is what I did and it worked perfectly for what I was looking to do:

```
Dim StatusDate As String
 StatusDate = InputBox("What status date do you want to pull?", "Enter Status Date", " ")

        If StatusDate = " " Then
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter a Status date to continue.")
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf StatusDate = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

This key was to set the default value of the input box to be an actual space, so a user pressing just the OK button would return a value of " " while pressing cancel returns ""

From a usability standpoint, the defaulted value in the input box starts highlighted and is cleared when a user types so the experience is no different than if the box had no value.

Answer (score 12):

```
input = InputBox("Text:")

If input <> "" Then
   ' Normal
Else
   ' Cancelled, or empty
End If
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa445028):

> If the user clicks Cancel, the function returns a zero-length string ("").

Comment: This would work, but is there a way to tell the difference between a cancel button push or an empty ok? (Like what Jamie posted below, but in a way that works with .NET)

Comment: The input box is very limited, as Jamie says, just write your own dialog instead.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a very old topic, but the correct answer is still not here.

The accepted answer works with a space, but the user can remove this space - so this answer is not reliable.
The answer of Georg works, but is needlessly complex.

To test if the user pressed cancel, just use the following code:

```
Dim Answer As String = InputBox("Question")
If String.ReferenceEquals(Answer, String.Empty) Then
    'User pressed cancel
Else if Answer = "" Then
    'User pressed ok with an empty string in the box
Else
    'User gave an answer
```

Comment: This was what worked for me. I'm not sure I exactly understand why. Is it because `String.Empty` is different from the empty string `""`?

Comment: This code is not checking on the value of String.Empty, but on the Instance.

Comment: This did not work for me fwiw - I assigned a default value to the inputbox and when I delete it and hit OK the IF statement here returns true

Comment: For me it also detects an empty input as cancel.

Answer (score 3):

1) create a Global function (best in a module so that you only need to declare once)

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices                 ' required imports
Public intInputBoxCancel as integer                    ' public variable

Public Function StrPtr(ByVal obj As Object) As Integer
    Dim Handle As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned)
    Dim intReturn As Integer = Handle.AddrOfPinnedObject.ToInt32
    Handle.Free()
    Return intReturn
End Function
```

2) in the form load event put this (to make the variable intInputBoxCancel = cancel event)

```
intInputBoxCancel = StrPtr(String.Empty)
```

3) now, you can use anywhere in your form (or project if StrPtr is declared global in module)

```
dim ans as string = inputbox("prompt")         ' default data up to you
if StrPtr(ans) = intInputBoxCancel then
   ' cancel was clicked
else
   ' ok was clicked (blank input box will still be shown here)
endif
```

Comment: For 64 bit, I had to use `Int64` instead of `Integer`. But it didn't work, treating empty input the same as the cancel button.

Comment: This method no longer works with the newer InputBox in Microsoft.VisualBasic Namespaces. The truly only way to know if Cancel or Ok was selected is to create your own InputBox function.

Comment: What was the older InputBox? Is that still available in the latest .NET Frameworks somewhere?

Comment: It's part of the Microsoft.VisualBasic NameSpace (in References). Best just to create your own InputBox control if you need the difference. It's easy.

Comment: The new one that doesn't work is in Microsoft.VisualBasic, isn't it? I'm wondering about the old one that this code did work on.

Answer (score 2):

I like using the IsNullOrEmpty method of the class String like so...

```
input = InputBox("Text:")

If String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) Then
   ' Cancelled, or empty
Else
   ' Normal
End If
```

Comment: Is it not possible to differentiate an empty value from the cancel action?

Comment: This doesn't work. It detects both the cancel button and an empty input as cancel because both are the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Base on @Theo69's answer, the following worked for me:

```
    Dim Answer As String = InputBox("Question", DefaultResponse:=vbCr)
    If Answer = "" Then
        'User pressed cancel
    ElseIf Answer = vbcr Then
        'User pressed ok with an empty string in the box
    Else
        'User gave an answer
        Dim Response As String = Answer.Replace(vbCr, "")
    End If
```

I used carriage return because I didn't like seeing a character in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a simpler way using the `DialogResult.cancel` method.

Eg:

```
Dim anInput as String = InputBox("Enter your pin")

If anInput <>"" then

   ' Do something
Elseif DialogResult.Cancel then

  Msgbox("You've canceled")
End if
```

Comment: On DialogResult I get Run-time error '424': Object required.

Comment: I get the cancel result for both pressing Cancel and entering nothing with OK.

Answer (score 0):

Base on @Theo69's answer, the following worked for me:

```
Dim answer As String = Nothing
answer = InputBox("Your answer")
If answer is Nothing Then
    'User clicked the Cancel button.
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the OP is 14 years old, this SO link is still top of the searches for proper handling InputBox Cancel.

OP was targeting VB.NET.
VBA/VB6 share some similarities.
VBScript is a slightly different animal.

In short, the "secret sauce" is VarType, which returns "0" for Cancel and "8" for null or actual string.

The following works in Win 10/11 via cscript.exe, wscript.exe and within Office 365 Access/Excel, meaning the code is portable as it is "late bindings" (no IDE lint/intellisense in Office).

```
Dim strResult
Dim strDefault: strDefault = "Something"

strResult = InputBox("Prompt", "Title", strDefault)
' MsgBox VarType(strResult)

' Handle Cancel
Select Case True
    ' Case StrPtr(strResult) = 0 ' Works in VBA, but not VBScript
    ' Case strResult = vbNullString ' Will catch empty/null also, which is sub-optimal
    Case VarType(strResult) = 0 ' Works in VBScript, but not VBA
        MsgBox "Cancel Pressed."
    Case Len(strResult) = 0
        MsgBox "Empty/Null String Accepted."
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Accepted = " & vbCrLf & strResult
End Select
```

Answer (score -1):

Guys remember that you can use the try catch end event

```
Dim Green as integer

Try
    Green = InputBox("Please enter a value for green")
    Catch ex as Exception
        MsgBox("Green must be a valid integer!")
End Try
```

Comment: Using `Try..Catch` for validation of inputs is generally bad practice. Its almost always better validate your inputs and use `Try..Catch` for the unexpexted

Comment: That doesn't distinguish cancel from empty input. Both throw an exception.

Answer (score -2):

Try this. I've tried the solution and it works.

```
Dim ask = InputBox("")
If ask.Length <> 0 Then
   // your code
Else
   // cancel or X Button 
End If
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The cancel button and empty input both return a length 0 string.

Answer (score -2):

Although this question is being asked for 5 years ago. I just want to share my answer. Below is how I detect whether someone is clicked cancel and OK button in input box:

```
Public sName As String

Sub FillName()
    sName = InputBox("Who is your name?")
    ' User is clicked cancel button
    If StrPtr(sName) = False Then
        MsgBox ("Please fill your name!")
        Exit Sub
    End If

   ' User is clicked OK button whether entering any data or without entering any datas
    If sName = "" Then
        ' If sName string is empty 
        MsgBox ("Please fill your name!")
    Else
        ' When sName string is filled
        MsgBox ("Welcome " & sName & " and nice see you!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: StrPtr is not available in VB.NET.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? As far I'm using the code, it works.

Answer (score -3):

```
Dim input As String

input = InputBox("Enter something:")

If StrPtr(input) = 0 Then
   MsgBox "You pressed cancel!"
Elseif input.Length = 0 Then
   MsgBox "OK pressed but nothing entered."
Else
   MsgBox "OK pressed: value= " & input
End If
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for conceptually, but StrPtr isn't valid in VB.NET

Answer (score -3):

```
Dim userReply As String
userReply = Microsoft.VisualBasic.InputBox("Message")
If userReply = "" Then 
  MsgBox("You did not enter anything. Try again")
ElseIf userReply.Length = 0 Then 
  MsgBox("You did not enter anything")
End If
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with VB style guide and there was no indentation in the answer, but I've tried to restore what was lost in formatting (and copy&paste?)

Comment: Under what condition can `userReply <> ""` and `userReply.Length = 0`?

Comment: This doesn't work. Both the cancel button and OK on an empty input go to the same branch of the If statement.

Answer (score -3):

Why not check if for nothing?

```
if not inputbox("bleh") = nothing then
'Code
else
' Error
end if
```

This is what i typically use,  because its a little easier to read.

Comment: Nothing is not the same as an empty string which is what is returned when the user clicks Cancel.

Comment: This doesn't work because InputBox returns an empty string on cancel, not `Nothing`.