# Inputbox Cancel OK and X button with Try & Catch exception handling in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, try-catch, inputbox

I have written a code to delete user input choice from input box the rest of the code is OK, but when user cancels or presses the OK (No Value inserted) or presses X still the Try & Catch exception shows conversion from type STRING to Decimal is not valid.
So I worked with below code but still failed! I wonder if anyone could help me in this!

I also tried to get help from this answer but still it does
[VB.NET Inputbox - How to identify when the Cancel Button is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923764/vb-net-inputbox-how-to-identify-when-the-cancel-button-is-pressed)
Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub btndelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btndelete.Click
    Try
        Dim isbn As Decimal = InputBox("Enter Book ISBN", "Delete")


    If ISBN = " " Then
        MessageBox.Show("You must enter an ISBN to continue.")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf StatusDate = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

        'Below command is performed with the help of SQL stored prodecures
        cmd = New SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM book WHERE isbn = @isbn) " _
& " BEGIN " _
& " delete from published_by where isbn = @isbn; " _
& " delete from book_return where isbn = @isbn; " _
& " delete from memberbook_issue where isbn = @isbn; " _
& " delete from book where isbn = @isbn;" _
& " SELECT 1; " _
& " END " _
& " ELSE SELECT 0", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@isbn", SqlDbType.Decimal, 13) With {.Value = isbn})

        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cn.Open()
        End If
        Dim returnValue As Integer = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        If returnValue = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully Deleted from current table & dependant table(s)", _
                            "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No Book record with provided ISBN", "Information", _
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("select b.staff_id 'Staff ID', b.pub_id 'Publisher ID', b.sub_code 'Subject Code', " _
                                & " b.isbn 'ISBN', b.book_name 'Book Name', b.author 'Author', b.price 'Price', " _
                                & " b.rack_no 'Rack No#', b.no_of_books 'No# of Books', pby.vol_no 'Volume No#', " _
                                & " pby.pub_date 'Publish Date' from book b join published_by pby " _
                                & " on b.isbn = pby.isbn", cn)
        dt = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        dgvbook.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Not Completed Because OF The Following Error " & "%" & ex.Message & "%", "Error", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the input box?

Comment: An inputbox returns an empty string when canceled or when the X is used. Test for that as a result and you should not have any issues.

Comment: @Plutonix it is above the code section but I don't know how bring it down to the code section :(  in this website

Comment: @steve I tried to put this on my code: 

        If Input = " " Then
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter an ISBN to continue.")
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf ISBN = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

Comment: Sorry, didnt see it in the unformatted part. InputBox returns a string; not a Decimal and Decimal seems an odd choice for an ISBN.  At any rate the linked question shows you what to do: test it and `Exit Sub` when it is empty

Comment: @Steve I know the above code in my comment should be working fine but I don't exactly know where to put that in my code

Comment: A better way to code that would be to let them pick from a list of ISBNs.

Comment: @Plutonix I used Decimal for ISBN cause INT can only support up to 10 digits long in vb but I need 13 digits for ISBN and yeah the code link which I shared, I tried to put it below the inputbox in my code, it doesn't work, because when I run and press cancel it still brings exception!

Comment: Let me just edit my post and add the code from the link I shared @Plutonix So you can tell me that the position I posted is correct or not?

Comment: A formatted ISBN, `978-3-16-148410-0` is not a number but a string. Users picking rather than typing them would result in fewer errors

Comment: Yeah @Plutonix but I use it like this 1000123456789 you know without the dashes :P but I understand you If you go for string type it will more standard and fewer errors will occur by users

Comment: You got the answer below *as* an answer complete with how to convert InputBox string to decimal.  You sort of miss the point: I would not abuse the user by making them find/type 13 digits to begin with (where are they going to get the number from?) then I would not use the very crude InputBox for it. **No** your code is not correct.  Study the answer below

Comment: @Plutonix Librarian is only managing this, it is not for students, he takes ISBNs from books normally all standard books have it! and yeah if I go by your suggestion to let him select from a list of ISBN then how he would insert new books (that has definitely new ISBNs for it) through another VB form(ISBN_List) ?

Comment: your question is about *deleting* a book, which means The System should already have the ISBN, which means they could pick from a list.  Librarians are people too

Comment: haha you are really smart bro actually I was frustrated by all day coding, So didn't thought about this! anyways coding is enough for day I will work on it tomorrow but thanks again for nice suggestions :)

Comment: Choosing from a list is a good idea, but it depends on how many titles are in the library. Imagine to choose between thousands, all numeric, list items (hopefully sorted). I suggest to provide a system to search for partial matches on ISBN and only then use a list. (but perhaps the only reasonable solution is a search for title or authors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would handle this if I HAD to use in inputbox:

```
Dim sResult as String = ""
Dim dResult as Decimal
Do    
    sResult = InputBox("Enter Book ISBN", "Delete")
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(sResult, dResult)
        Messagebox.show("...")
    Else
        Exit Loop
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: `...if I HAD to use in inputbox`  == +1